# WiFi Connection Lost Periodically - Must Reboot iPod Touch to Restore

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

I have a 2nd generation iPod Touch running OS 4 that I (usually) leave powered on 24x7. What I notice that I am unable to go online - I cannot check my email, browse the web, etc. My guess is that my wireless router's DHCP tables have recycled (or whatever the right word is) and that the iPod Touch needs to renew its IP address.

If I go to the iPod Touch's Settings it lists my network and the DHCP-granted IP address, DNS settings, and so forth. If I try to renew the lease the existing settings are erased and the iPod thinks for a while before bringing up a new IP address. However, this new one starts with 169.254 (or something like that) when it should start with 192.168. Needless to say, the connectivity problems persist.

The only way I can get back online is to power down the iPod Touch then power it back on, which takes upwards of a minute. Is this a known problem with the iPod Touch? Is it an issue with my router? Am I stuck rebooting the iPod Touch when this situation unfolds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers starting with 169... are self assigned numbers and means the iPhone can't find a DHCP server to connect to.
This used to happen to my iPhone on an earlier OS version (3 point something). I haven't seen it for a while. Switching to and from "Airplane Mode" was enough to get the iPhone to acquire a new address.

PS. Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Next time this happens (which will probably be by mid-week) I'll give the airplane mode switcharoo a try and report back with my findings. Thanks!

Comment: This morning the WiFi didn't work - toggling the airplane mode did the trick - much faster than rebooting the iPod Touch! Thank you for a workaround for this problem.